# Accessing specific instance in a loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm just starting to learn AS3 and have encountered a problem on which I'm stuck. I have created a `MovieClip` called `Button` and added three instances on my stage called: `button1`, `button2` and `button3`. What I want to achieve is that when I hover my mouse cursor over one of the buttons, I want all the other buttons to do something; in my example: change the `alpha` setting to 0.2. I have been able to do this with a lot of lines of code, but I want to reduce the code to as little as possible using an `array` and `for each` statement.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

var arrayButtons:Array = [button1, button2, button3];
for each (var btn in arrayButtons) {
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBtn);
    arrayButtons.splice[this, 1];
}

function onBtn(e:MouseEvent): void {
for (var i:Number = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {
    arrayButtons[i].alpha = 0.2;
}
}
```

The `line arrayButtons.splice[this, 1];` doesn't work, but I have no idead what I should change this to. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splicing an array requires two integers and `this` is not going to be an integer.

Even if `this` was the integer you were thinkng, it would loop through and remove a button on each loop, leaving you with an empty array. I can see what you were trying to do - allocate an array without the relevant button for each handler.

A simple way with your code is to run a check in your onBtn handler's for loop to see if the current array element matches the rolled over button (e.currentTarget). If it doesn't, set the alpha.

You don't need to splice the array.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

var arrayButtons:Array = [button1, button2, button3];
for each (var btn in arrayButtons) {
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBtn);

    // remove the splice
    // arrayButtons.splice[this, 1];
}

function onBtn(e:MouseEvent): void {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {

        // if the current array element is not the current button, set alpha
        if(arrayButtons[i].name != e.currentTarget.name ){
        arrayButtons[i].alpha = 0.2;
        }

    }
}
```

(mods: I couldn't figure out as3 code highlighting - you used to be able to highlight as3 syntax but it's been a while since I've tried in SO?)

Comment: Wow, I never thought to solve it in this way! Thanks for the help!